# Console in Eclipse isn't showing output

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having trouble with console window in Eclipse because it isn't showing real output. (stdout)

For example when this program is executed:

```
public class delila {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The console of Eclipse is showing output like this:

```
 Eclipse Compiler for Java(TM) v20150120-1634, 3.10.2
 Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2013. All rights reserved.

 Usage:  
 If directories are specified, then their source contents are compiled.
 Possible options are listed below. Options enabled by default are prefixed
 with '+'.

 Classpath options:
    -cp -classpath 
                       specify location for application classes and sources.
                       Each directory or file can specify access rules for
                       types between '[' and ']' (e.g. [-X] to forbid
                       access to type X, [~X] to discourage access to type X,
                       [+p/X;-p/*] to forbid access to all types in package p
                       but allow access to p/X)
    -bootclasspath 
                       specify location for system classes. Each directory or
                       file can specify access rules for types between '['
                       and ']'
    -sourcepath 
                       specify location for application sources. Each directory
                       or file can specify access rules for types between '['
                       and ']'. Each directory can further specify a specific
                       destination directory using a '-d' option between '['
                       and ']'; this overrides the general '-d' option.
                       .class files created from source files contained in a
                       jar file are put in the user.dir folder in case no
                       general '-d' option is specified. ZIP archives cannot
                       override the general '-d' option
    -extdirs 
                       specify location for extension ZIP archives
    -endorseddirs 
                       specify location for endorsed ZIP archives
    -d            destination directory (if omitted, no directory is
                       created); this option can be overridden per source
                       directory
    -d none            generate no .class files
    -encoding     specify default encoding for all source files. Each
                       file/directory can override it when suffixed with
                       '['']' (e.g. X.java[utf8]).
                       If multiple default encodings are specified, the last
                       one will be used.

 Compliance options:
    -1.3               use 1.3 compliance (-source 1.3 -target 1.1)
    -1.4             + use 1.4 compliance (-source 1.3 -target 1.2)
    -1.5 -5 -5.0       use 1.5 compliance (-source 1.5 -target 1.5)
    -1.6 -6 -6.0       use 1.6 compliance (-source 1.6 -target 1.6)
    -1.7 -7 -7.0       use 1.7 compliance (-source 1.7 -target 1.7)
    -1.8 -8 -8.0       use 1.8 compliance (-source 1.8 -target 1.8)
    -source   set source level: 1.3 to 1.8 (or 5, 5.0, etc)
    -target   set classfile target: 1.1 to 1.8 (or 5, 5.0, etc)
                       cldc1.1 can also be used to generate the StackMap
                       attribute

 Warning options:
    -deprecation     + deprecation outside deprecated code (equivalent to
                       -warn:+deprecation)
    -nowarn -warn:none disable all warnings
    -nowarn:[]
                       specify directories from which optional problems should
                       be ignored
    -?:warn -help:warn display advanced warning options

 Error options:
    -err:    convert exactly the listed warnings
                                      to be reported as errors
    -err:+   enable additional warnings to be
                                      reported as errors
    -err:-   disable specific warnings to be
                                      reported as errors

 Setting warning or error options using properties file:
    -properties    set warnings/errors option based on the properties
                          file contents. This option can be used with -nowarn,
                          -err:.. or -warn:.. options, but the last one on the
                          command line sets the options to be used.

 Debug options:
    -g[:lines,vars,source] custom debug info
    -g:lines,source  + both lines table and source debug info
    -g                 all debug info
    -g:none            no debug info
    -preserveAllLocals preserve unused local vars for debug purpose

 Annotation processing options:
   These options are meaningful only in a 1.6 environment.
    -Akey[=value]        options that are passed to annotation processors
    -processorpath 
                         specify locations where to find annotation processors.
                         If this option is not used, the classpath will be
                         searched for processors
    -processor 
                         qualified names of the annotation processors to run.
                         This bypasses the default annotation discovery process
    -proc:only           run annotation processors, but do not compile
    -proc:none           perform compilation but do not run annotation
                         processors
    -s              destination directory for generated source files
    -XprintProcessorInfo print information about which annotations and elements
                         a processor is asked to process
    -XprintRounds        print information about annotation processing rounds
    -classNames 
                         qualified names of binary classes to process

 Advanced options:
    @            read command line arguments from file
    -maxProblems    max number of problems per compilation unit (100 by
                       default)
    -log         log to a file. If the file extension is '.xml', then
                       the log will be a xml file.
    -proceedOnError[:Fatal]
                       do not stop at first error, dumping class files with
                       problem methods
                       With ":Fatal", all optional errors are treated as fatal
    -verbose           enable verbose output
    -referenceInfo     compute reference info
    -progress          show progress (only in -log mode)
    -time              display speed information 
    -noExit            do not call System.exit(n) at end of compilation (n==0
                       if no error)
    -repeat         repeat compilation process  times for perf analysis
    -inlineJSR         inline JSR bytecode (implicit if target >= 1.5)
    -enableJavadoc     consider references in javadoc
    -parameters        generate method parameters attribute (for target >= 1.8)
    -genericsignature  generate generic signature for lambda expressions
    -Xemacs            used to enable emacs-style output in the console.
                       It does not affect the xml log output
    -missingNullDefault  report missing default nullness annotation

    -? -help           print this help message
    -v -version        print compiler version
    -showversion       print compiler version and continue

 Ignored options:
    -J         pass option to virtual machine (ignored)
    -X         specify non-standard option (ignored
                       except for listed -X options)
    -X                 print non-standard options and exit (ignored)
    -O                 optimize for execution time (ignored)
```

Is anyone who can help to get real output (stdout), "Hello world", instead of this text.

Thank you.

### EDIT:

I run it with `ctrl+F11`

This is the image of eclipse:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking the right most downward arrow in the Console views controls? This may give more options for which console you see the output for (you're looking for the Process Console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was getting a bit long for a comment:

Specifically how are you running this program?

What is the name of the console that is displaying this text? It should be just below the `Console` tab and above the first line of text.

In the console view there are icon options, when hovered on they display their names, use the `X` to close this console that you do not want.

Also, check "Display Selected Console" and "Open Console" to see if there is any console available that corresponds to the running/completed program

**EDIT:**

It looks like `ctrl + F11` is running something called `Main [5]` as a `Java Application` rather than `delila`. Try running this class directly, right click on the source file, `Run As` `Java Application`. See how that works.

Comment: I run it with ctrl+F11. The name of console is Console as you can see from image

Comment: @HardRock try running this file directly rather than `ctrl + F11`

Comment: You're right..  Main [5] is called instead of my class..running directly solved this problem. Thank you